# Very long range wireless communication between two arduinos(500-1000 KM)

Tags: arduino-uno, communication, wireless

I searched for very long range wireless communications between two Arduinos, but can't find solutions. I don't live in USA, In my country there are regions, where GSM does not work.
I want wireless communication approximately 500-1 000 KMs.
What are options without GSM for that distance wireless communication(500-1000 KM)?

Comment: What do you want to send between them? How many bytes and how often?

Comment: I want to send text and voice, 4096 bytes in 1-5 seconds interval

Comment: Do you have a budget in mind for the initial build? Ongoing costs?

Comment: Satelite communication is expensive, but that can be used for voice and for short data messages. The short data messages are used for example by ships. Do you have a shortwave license for an extremely powerful transmitter ? As far as I know, everything else is illegal.

Comment: I don't have license, but I have budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the old days, we used things called modems to connect computers across POTS.

[image: old modems]

Your country may not have GMS, but I bet you still have old land lines. In that case, you can use a land line + modem to connect the arduinos directly , no Internet involved, no ISP needed, no overhead, no lag, nothing. It's just one Arduino at each end of a very long cable. No TCP/IP needed, but you need your own protocol to keep data in sync and filter out errors. There is lot of well proven ones from the golden era of BBS.

I search Aliexpress, I didn't find any modem suitable for direct conection with Arduino, but there is a lot of USB modem like this:

[image: USB Modem]

I don't know if they can work with Arduino. I'm afraid that they are *win-modem* only.

What it really works with anything is a traditional modem, like this [model](https://www.multitech.com/brands/multimodem-zba) from Multitech (not an endorsing):

[image: Multitech modem]

You will need a RS-232 level converter however, because RS-232's voltages can go up to 25V. The converter avoids you to deal with the peculiarities of the RS-232 standard and DB-9 connector.

[image: RS232-TTL level converter]

And a cable, of course.

You can develop and test your project using a *null modem* cable, to connect both Arduinos, a few meters apart, without need of a land line.

Answer (score 1):

> What are options without GSM for that distance wireless communication(500-1000 KM)?

1) use the internet;

2) use narrow band transmission, like qrp;

3) use relays;

4) use satellite phones;

5) use a high-powered lw transceivers.

6) ...